# How to extend non-client GWT classes

Tags: gwt, binding, deferred

For my project I've trying to extend GWT classes that not inherited with client modules.
For example I want to create a simple implementation of com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator.

```
public class SimpleResourceGenerator implements ResourceGenerator
```

and use instead of ClientBundle's default @ResourceGeneratorType - BundleResourceGenerator

```
@ResourceGeneratorType(SimpleResourceGenerator.class)
    public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
```

but unsuccess.

If I place my SimpleResourceGenerator class under "client" package, GWT compiler says:

```
         [ERROR] Line 11: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JMethod; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 14: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleFields; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 36: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleRequirements; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

If I link all gwt-user and gwt-dev sources to project I have other unresolved dependencies.

```
Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.animation.Animation'
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
         Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CrossSiteIframeLinker'
            [ERROR] Unable to load class 'com.google.gwt.core.linker.DirectInstallLinker'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.linker.DirectInstallLinker
```

I can't understand the GWT compiler and how it resolves types while compile-time. Why it finds some of GWT classes and can't find the others.

The only way I see is to compile SimpleResourceGenerator's module rewriting

```
   <generate-with
    class="com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.StaticClientBundleGenerator">

    <!-- We have to specify on which types to execute the Generator -->
    <when-type-assignable
      class="com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle" />
   </generate-with>
```

from inherited com.google.gwt.resources.Resources.gwt.xml with own generator

```
  <generate-with
    class="com.example.gwt.SimpleBundleGenerator">
      <when-type-assignable
        class="com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle" />
  </generate-with>
```

and extend com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.

But it seems a little too complex to me.
Is there a more simple way to extend GWT classes than deferred binding via generators and code replacement?

Comment: Should be easier than that. Have you tried inheriting the module? http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml

Comment: Yes, the module inherits Resources.gwt.xml which sources in com.google.gwt.resources.client package, but ResourceGenerator is in com.google.gwt.resources.ext package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators should not be included in a "client" package, but the java sources it generates should.

The "client" package is for the gwt-compile to find the java source files that it should use when compiling your app to javascript and a Generator is used to produce javasource files on compiletime.